# How to ignore mouse events on a mapbox layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've built a marker on my Mapbox map that looks like this when a user mouse over it:

[image]

The issue I'm running into is that the document icon is a separate layer from the background pin. This is so users can upload custom icons. When using the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events to create a hover popup on the background pin layer, the popup flickers when the user hovers over the icon layer. This is because the user is technically leaving the background pin layer.

I know there are javascript hacks to potentially do this that are messy, but what I'm really looking for is a way to "ignore" events on a mapbox layer. Is this possible?

Edit: The markers here are rendered as a Mapbox layer, not as HTML markers and are thus drawn using the canvas (I believe), so using CSS to ignore events is not possible.

Comment: It'd be a bit clearer what's going on if you include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of registering events per layer, you could register the mousemove event without specifying the layer and use queryRenderedFeatures to see if the cursor is on either of your two layers.

Another approach is use a technique like https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/ and create a composited image client side so you only have the one layer.

Comment: Ended up using queryRenderedFeatures, but I'm somewhat concerned about performance. As of now, it works great!

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to ignore mouse events using CSS is to use the style property `pointer-events:none` this will not trigger any pointer(mouse) events on the element

Comment: Good suggestion, I don't think this will work in my case since these are not HTML markers and are rendered via the canvas. I can't use HTML markers because they are not performant when you have thousands of points.