# mousemove with two layers on top of each other (overlapping)

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

The closest to my question are: [Mapbox gl js - overlapping layers and mouse event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294242/mapbox-gl-js-overlapping-layers-and-mouse-event-handling), [Mapbox add popup on hover (layer), close on mouseleave, but keep open on popup hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866651/mapbox-add-popup-on-hover-layer-close-on-mouseleave-but-keep-open-on-popup-h) and [How to ignore mouse events on a mapbox layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555583/how-to-ignore-mouse-events-on-a-mapbox-layer/) - but they don't answer it.

I have two layers, let's imagine one is for a country, and another is for a city. Both of them a handled like this:

```
// CountryLayer.js
map.on("mousemove", "country-layer", e => {
   // show info about the country 
   featureProps = e.features[0] // display some notification from the props
   ...

// CityLayer.js
map.on("mousemove", "city-layer", e => {
   // show info about the city
   featureProps = e.features[0] // display some notification from the props
   ...
```

It's done in different components. But when I mouseover `city-layer` mapbox thinks that I'm still "mousemoving" on top of the `country-layer` as well, so I get two notifications from separate components, where I need only one - in that case from the `city-layer` cause it's on top of `country-layer`.

Handling the `mousemove` without layerId in one place is gonna be a mess and breaks all the good rules about programming. Creating external "event manager" which will track whether I'm hovering the city and if is so will remove `mousemove` event from `country-layer` - is complex. I didn't find any good alternatives. At least, I would be glad to disable pointer events for a layer like this:

```
map.on("mousemove", "city-layer", e => {
   map.getLayer("country-layer").setStyle({ "pointer-events": false })
   featureProps = e.features[0]
   ...
```

or something like this. Is it possible? Is there more adequate way around it?

`e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();` does not work

Comment: Can you please make a runnable example using a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

It appears, that you can do `e.originalEvent.preventDefault();` in the `city-layer` and add a check `e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented` in the `country-layer` from the example.

However, I have issues with z-index position of layers: `map.moveLayer("city-layer", "country-layer");` or vice-vise doesn't actually change the way, event propogates, so for some reason my `country-layer` always come first, so when it checks for `e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented`, `preventDefault()` wasn't fired yet, so it comes always `false`.

But technically, this answers my question.

Comment: Nice, I've implemented it that way. What I found out is that the order of registering the event handlers is the z-index. First event handler is top-most layer.

Answer (score 0):

`map.on` can listen on multiple layers at once. With events like `mousemove` it returns features in reverse layer order (from "highest" to "lowest").

So the way to do this is:

```
map.on("mousemove", ["city-layer", "country-layer"], e => {
   feature = e.features[0]
   if (feature.layer.id === 'city-layer') {
     // ...
   } else {
     // ...
   }
});
```

Comment: true, but as I mentioned in the issue, handling all the layers at one place is gonna be a mess if you have layers separated into different components, and want it to work independently.

I came up with a "store" that tracks which layers are loaded, so I can assign event handler at the right time to make `preventDefault()` work.

Comment: I write code like this frequently. It's not "a mess". The one handler looks at the mouse movement and then emits events like "city-hover" or "country-click" as appropriate. It's fine, really.

Comment: I'm happy it works for you, it's just not the way I want my codebase to be like. Thanks for the suggestion :)